# how to set default folder in swi-prolog on mac

Tags: macos, swi-prolog

I want to set the **default folder** for programs in swi-prolog.
I have noticed that I can change the personalization file '**.plrc**' in my home folder but I do not know the rules to edit this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your `.swiplrc` file (`.plrc` file in old SWI-Prolog versions) an `initialization/1` directive with a goal that changes the current directory to whatever you want. For example:

```
:- initialization(cd('$HOME/my_fancy_prolog_project')).
```

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find the manual of these instructions.

Comment: On the SWI-Prolog website, you can use the search box on the top right to search the documentation for directives and predicates.

Comment: Almost 4 years later. This did not work for me. Had to create the file `.swiplrc`.

Comment: @Stefan Recent SWI-Prolog versions switched from `.plrc` to `.swiplrc`.

Comment: Sim Paulo, noticed/guessed this after half an hour searching for my own fault ;-) It was my first SWI-Prolog day. Perhaps you want to edit your answer above to reflect the changes.